# How can I set a specific value to be returned by a mock_request in python when an argument is passed into request.get() in the code?

Tags: python, request, mocking

My code:

```
def my_function():
    page = requests.get(PRODUCTS)

    return page.text

@mock.patch(...request)
def test_unit_test(...): 
    mock_response = MagicMock()
    mock_response.text.return_value = 'whatever'
    mock_requests.get.return_value = mock_response



print(my_function())  => 'whatever'
```

I am trying to add to `mock_response` such that when `next_page_link` is passed as an argument in `request.get(next_page_link)`, I want `mock_request` to be assigned to `None`.

All of the above works, like I have demonstrated in the last line; when I do something like `var1 = page.text` then `var1` will point to `whatever`.

What I am struggling with is to set `mock_response` to a certain value when a certain argument is passed into `request.get()`.

Comment: could you add more code please. For example set a complete @mock.patch(...request) instruction. How can you execute my_function()? In the test function test_unit_test()? I can't reply your code in my system so I can't give you any suggestions.